# How to get webhook notification from facebook when a post is made in facebook with specific string in it

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-webhooks

I want to get notification whenever a post is made in a facebook group and the title has some specific string. Is that even possible? I am not owner of the group but just a member

Comment: No, that is not possible. There is no webhook functionality for group feeds for normal groups outside the Workplace environment to begin with.